# Changing color of value fields in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, templates

I'm finishing a Word template in Word 2013. I started from an original one and applied our colors and logo. There's just one issue which I cannot get right.
I'm using some fields that were on the template: date and author. As you can see on the screenshot, I've changed the color for the anchor (blue-ish):
[image]

But when I start to enter a value, it changes to the initial color of the template:
[image]

I've tried changing the color in several ways:
Right click - lettertype (or maybe font-type in english). When I change the value from orange to blue, click ok, return to those properties, the changes are inverted.

[image]

This is the same for other methods, like f.e. design tab.

Is it possible to change that color in the template without having to change the anchor (text generated on the field)?

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to change, and trying to avoid changing, but to change the colour of typed text, you should be able to modify the style from the control's Properties dialog. To change the colour of the Placeholder text, you can click "Design view", select the text and change the colour. (NB, IMO you are more likely to get more useful "views" here if you tag as microsoft-word as well as microsoft-word-2013).

Comment: @bibadia: I tagged MS Word, but someone edited my tags. I'll try to add the tag, good feedback. About the post, changing the  placeholder text works, so the template "looks" fine. When someone selects the template and enters a value in the placeholder (authorname), the color switches again (from blue to orange in this case). I need to change the color of the value of the placeholder. When going to design view and changing the color, after pressing apply, it seems to work. Going back to it I see it didn't "save" the change, it reverts everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it's a very subtle problem:

When selecting the placeholder, you select the content. Notice the grey placeholder indicator "Titel".

[image]

If you want to change the entire placeholder, you have to make sure the placeholder is selected. You know you got the placeholder selected when "Titel" has a darker grey background:

[image]

Now changes are made to the placeholder (like the color, that's what I needed).